# Git asking for password, but not for username

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, web-deployment

I'm working in a team and we use bitbucket for our code. We also have one live server that we use for testing our app. Everyone in team has an SSH access to this server. To publish newest code on server, a member of team should login via SSH and execute `git pull` command.

However, when I open my bitbucket repo, it shows cloning URL in this format https://MY-USERNAME@bitbucket.org/MY-TEAM-NAME/REPO-NAME
and I used it to clone the repo. Now, when I use `git clone`, git uses MY-USERNAME and asks for password only. But I want it to ask for username as well, because another member of the team might ssh into this server and do `git pull`.

Looks like I'm using wrong URL, because it has got my username in it. Where do I get a generic one without username?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply remove `MY-USERNAME@` from the beginning of the URL, then Git will ask for both. HTTP lets you authenticate with `user:pass@host.com` at the beginning of a URL, and BitBucket tries to be helpful by supplying you with your personal URL to save you typing.

Proof of concept using BitBucket's example app:

```
$ git clone https://newuserme@bitbucket.org/newuserme/bb101repo.git
Cloning into 'bb101repo'...
Password for 'https://newuserme@bitbucket.org':

$ git clone https://bitbucket.org/newuserme/bb101repo.git
Cloning into 'bb101repo'...
Username for 'https://bitbucket.org': someoneelse
Password for 'https://someoneelse@bitbucket.org':
```